# How to add results from a promise based API call with message.addReply using Recast.ai?

Tags: javascript, facebook, promise, bots, sap-conversational-ai

I'm making a bot that searches restaurants based on location. Can anyone help me why this doesnt show up in FB messenger?:

```
restaurants(result.getMemory('location').raw)
.then(res=>{

  message.addReply(res);
  message.reply();

 });
}
```

The call to the restaurants function returns the results from a YELP API call (an array of restaurants) but when I add it as a reply to message, nothing happens in FB messenger.

Here is the full code for message.js:

```
    const recastai = require('recastai');

    const restaurants = require('./restaurants');

     // This function is the core of the bot behaviour
    const replyMessage = (message) => {
     // Instantiate Recast.AI SDK, just for request service
     const request = new recastai.request(process.env.REQUEST_TOKEN, 
    process.env.LANGUAGE);
   // Get text from message received
   const text = message.content;

    console.log('I receive: ', text);

  // Get senderId to catch unique conversation_token
  const senderId = message.senderId;

  // Call Recast.AI SDK, through /converse route
  request.converseText(text, { conversationToken: senderId })
  .then(result => {

    //Recast takes text analyses that, returns a result object, generates replies adds messages to reply stack and then sends the replies

    //Call Yelp API with when the intent is Location. When Yelp returns result we add it to the result.replies array. 
    //Then we add everything in result.replies to the messaging queue that sends the responses to FB


    if (result.action) {

      console.log('The conversation action is: ', result.action.slug);

    }

    // If there is not any message return by Recast.AI for this current conversation
    if (!result.replies.length) {
      message.addReply({ type: 'text', content: 'I don\'t have the reply to this yet :)' });
    } else {
      // Add each reply received from API to replies stack
      result.replies.forEach(replyContent => message.addReply({ type: 'text', content: replyContent }));
    }

    // Send all replies
    message.reply()
    //send initial reply generated by Recast first
    .then(() => {
    //call restaurant function that returns a list of results from API  
    //if the action is location and done
      if(result.action && result.action.slug === 'location' && result.action.done){

        restaurants(result.getMemory('location').raw)
          .then(res=>{

            console.log(res);

            message.addReply(res);
            message.reply();

          });

      }

    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error('Error while sending message to channel', err);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Error while sending message to Recast.AI', err);
  });
};

module.exports = replyMessage;
```

And here is my restaurants.js code that is imported into the message.js file for the bot behavior:

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

// Load configuration
require('./config');

const restaurants = (location) => {
  return Promise.all([
    yelpCall(location)
  ]).then(result => {

    //result contains the return value from Yelp call

    return result;

  });
};

const yelpCall = (location) => {

  const auth = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id='+ process.env.YELP_APP_ID +'&client_secret='+process.env.APP_SECRET
  };

  return rp(auth)
    .then(result => {
    const tokens = JSON.parse(result);
    return tokens;

  })
  .then(result=>{

    const options = {
      url: 'https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=' + location + "&term=thai",
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " + result.access_token}  
    };

    return rp(options).then(findings =>{

      return findings;

    });

  });

};

module.exports = restaurants;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few thoughts :

1. `message.reply` is thenable, therefore `return message.reply()` in two places.
2. `request.converseText()` is thenable, therefore `return request.converseText(...)`.
3. `restaurants` is thenable, therefore `return restaurants(...)`.
4. in `message.js`, `message.addReply()` is passed object of the form `{type:..., content:...}` in two places but finally just `res`. Is that correct?
5. in `restaurants.js`, `Promise.all()` appears to be unnecessary. It will cause its result to be wrapped in an array. `module.exports = location => yelpCall(location);` seems more appropriate.

Comment: it worked for me with these comments, thanks! why are the returns necessary?

Comment: It works like this: // Send all replies
    return message.reply()
    .then(() => {
      if(result.action && result.action.slug === 'location' && result.action.done){       
        return restaurants(result.getMemory('location').raw)
          .then(res=>{
            message.addReply(res);
            return message.reply();
         
          });
    
      }
    }) 
Why is the last return in "return message.reply" needed?

Comment: The initial `return` is required to return a promise to the function's caller. 
Returns within a promise chain (all the way down to the innermost nested functions) are necessary to inform the chain (and thence the function's caller) of synchronous values and/or asynchronous resolution/value/error.